# Getting error when running SSIS Package in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have set up a new SSIS package into SQL Server 2008. I have an excel spreadsheet having 8000+ data and using 64 bit system.

when running the package, I am getting attached error message. Please can you suggest what is the wrong in this error log.

[image]

Comment: [Load Data Excel SSIS 32bit vs 64bit](http://www.madeiradata.com/load-data-excel-ssis-32-bit-vs-64-bit/) -> Run64BitRuntime = False

Comment: (make sure you have the correct access driver installed too)

Comment: Driver means??? I am using windows 10 64 bit system and SQL server 2008. SQL server is probably compatible for 32 bit system. What is the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of the ACE driver do you have installed? If the driver is 32 bit then go to SSIS Project -> Properties and then set Run64BitRuntime = False. Hope it helps.

Comment: I did it but it didn't work. It seems some driver issue but I am unable to identify

Comment: Please share the driver details. Also, you could try uninstalling and reinstalling the driver, should be fairly quick.

Comment: Did that help??